# Can JDWP be used in a real device without ADB?

Tags: android, android-debug, adb

Android's DVM uses a DDM protocol on top of JDWP protol. In the documentation and in the examples ADB is needed as a brige (indeed ADB is an Android Debugging Bridge).

My question is: Is possible to develop an APK with all DDM or JDWP protocol in order to trace apps in a real device? Or is there any protection?

Answer (score 2):

Android apps are configured to talk to the ADB daemon for JDWP connections.  DDMS queries the ADB daemon to get the list of debuggable processes.  (Type `adb jdwp` to see the list yourself.)

If Dalvik were configured to listen to a TCP socket, you could use `adb forward` to set up port-forwarding and just connect your debugger to it directly through TCP.  Development was done this way in the very early days, before DDMS existed.

(To this very day, around line 4185 in [ActivityThread](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java), you can see it announce that it's waiting on port 8100.  History buffs may also find the "Connection Establishment" section in the [DDMS design doc](http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/debugmon.html) interesting.  Not sure why that doc is all in italics.)

As it stands, the Dalvik VM is only listening for connections through ADB, so you can't attach a JDWP-based debugger to an app any other way.

Comment: Although all of this is useful information (all known) the question still open. Is any way (faking adb) to access to JDWP. For now in the emulator I have an APK which can adb forward and make the JDWP handshake. What I dont know if this will work on real devices. Maybe with Debug USB enable? Well I think I'll autoanswer me in 2 o 3 days. :) But tanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "faking ADB" -- you have ADB on a real device, why would you need to fake it?

Comment: Maybe fake is not the word I was looking for. I was trying to say that I'm acting as a ADB client but inside the device. Impersonating maybe? I don't know but the idea is that I'm "speaking" with the ADB Server to open a JDWP channel.

Comment: So you want to connect like a debugger, but from a process on the device rather than the host (e.g. maybe the device isn't plugged into anything)?  I don't think that'll work -- the adbd running on the device is only listening to USB for connections.